# How to clear the shell and print on the same line?

Tags: printing

I have this print statment:

```
print('current temp=' , cpu_temp , '   Min =' , min_temp , '  Max =' , max_temp , '  Temp Dif =' , temp_dif)
```

There is a loop in it so it keeps updating the temperature every 10 seconds.  Problem is it prints a new line each time. so I get this output:

```
current temp= 40.78    Min = 40.78   Max = 40.78   Temp Dif = 0.00
current temp= 40.24    Min = 40.24   Max = 40.78   Temp Dif = 0.54
current temp= 40.78    Min = 40.24   Max = 40.78   Temp Dif = 0.54
current temp= 40.78    Min = 40.24   Max = 40.78   Temp Dif = 0.54
```

How can I make it clear the current line and update the information.
I am running this in the THONNY Shell.

Answer (score 0):

got it to work with

```
 end='\r'
```

as the last part of my print statement.

```
print('current temp=' , cpu_temp , '   Min =' , min_temp , '  Max =' , max_temp , '  Temp Dif =' , temp_dif, end='\r')
```